# Core Data: performance issue. Instruments's output is cryptic

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit

I am using Core Data and RestKit in a basic way (just the default RestKit setup).

From time to time, the UI gets stuck for a very long time (50s on an iPhone 5). There can be quite a few objects, but nothing crazy and objects are small (no images etc).

I suspect it is due to some context saving, but I am not sure: never in my app do I save things manually.

Instruments' Time Profiler clearly shows what gets stuck, but I don't understand the output nor what's causing this. The Heaviest Stack Trace looks like this:

```
14  57129.0  Main Thread  0x4ea79 :0
13 CoreData 56680.0  -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:]
12 CoreData 56523.0  -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]
11 CoreData 56462.0  -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) executeRequest:withContext:error:]
10 CoreData 56442.0  -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NestedContextSupport) _parentObjectsForFetchRequest:inContext:error:]
 9 CoreData 56291.0  -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]
 8 CoreData 50210.0  -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:]
 7 CoreData 50193.0  -[NSMappedObjectStore executeFetchRequest:withContext:]
 6 CoreData 49978.0  -[NSDictionaryStoreMap handleFetchRequest:]
 5 Foundation 36516.0  -[NSPredicate evaluateWithObject:]
 4 Foundation 35865.0  -[NSComparisonPredicate evaluateWithObject:substitutionVariables:]
 3 Foundation 16845.0  -[NSFunctionExpression expressionValueWithObject:context:]
 2 CoreData 11823.0  -[NSDictionaryMapNode valueForKey:]
 1 CoreFoundation 1225.0  -[__NSCFString isEqualToString:]
 0 libobjc.A.dylib 36.0  -[NSObject class]
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It looks like you are executing a long fetch request (50s to save on CoreData would be an enormous save) on the main thread. Long operations (network, database etc...) should be executed on a background thread and then updates to the UI executed on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks @RoboticCat. The thing is I don't even know what is triggering this fetch (nor what it really is actually). It is done via a private API _parentObjectsForFetchRequest.

Comment: Somewhere (either in your code or in one of your included frameworks) there is heavy CoreData activity. Where this happens only you can tell; there must be a sequence of steps that leads to this activity. I'm surprised that you never save CoreData manually (is this a UIManagedDocument?) but regardless you will have to work out where this happens. Have a play with the check-boxes in the `Call Tree` (like `Hide System Libraries`) so you can try and track down what's calling the CoreData commands.

Comment: Also, there's a `Core Data` profiling option; I'm not sure it'll help but there may be something in it.

Comment: What does profiling show? RestKit would not usually run any fetch on the main thread...

Comment: Sorry @Wain: what do you mean by profiling? Something different than the Time Profiler output?

Comment: Preferably using the Core Data instrument which shows you lots of detail about fetching and such

Comment: It looks like I was wrong: the problem is not one big fetch or save in the main thread, but rather thousands of small fetch requests (1 object each time) occurring successively in the main thread and making the UI stagger. The problem is Core Data instrument shows that these fetches happen in the run loop, and I have no idea what is triggering them. Is there a way to tell? I suspect it is the NSFetchedResultsController but I don't know how to validate this hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting your managed object cache to `RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache` during core data setup?  I tried this after seeing this issue on github: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/issues/1232 and it significantly sped up my restkit/core data benchmarks.  Here is what the code looks like:

`objectManager.managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext: managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];`

From the RestKit docs at http://restkit.org/api/0.20.0/Classes/RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache.html: "(RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache) Provides a fast managed object cache where-in object instances are retained in memory to avoid hitting the Core Data persistent store. Performance is greatly increased over fetch request based strategy at the expense of memory consumption."